# Counting and grouping with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

My goal is simply to count the number of records in each hour of each day.  I thought a simple solution could be found with the `dplyr` or `data.table` packages:

My data set is extremely simple:

```
> head(test)
        id       date hour
1 14869663 2018-01-24   17
2 14869664 2018-01-24   17
3 14869665 2018-01-24   17
4 14869666 2018-01-24   17
5 14869667 2018-01-24   17
6 14869668 2018-01-24   17
```

I only need to group by two variables (date and hour) and count.  The `id` doesn't matter.  However, these two methods in `dplyr` do not seem to produce the desired result (a data frame of the same length of the input data, which includes millions of records, is the output).  What am I doing wrong here?

```
test %>% group_by(date, hour) %>% mutate(count = n())
test %>% add_count(date, hour)
```

The output would look something like this

```
> head(output)
n_records       date hour
1 700      2018-01-24   0
2 750      2018-01-24   1
3 730      2018-01-24   2
4 700      2018-01-24   3
5 721      2018-01-24   4
6 753      2018-01-24   5
```

and so on

any suggestions?

Comment: `test %>% group_by(date, hour) %>% mutate(count = n())` this should have worked. Can you create a small reproducible example which can help us to solve the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
library(dplyr)
starwars %>% 
    group_by(gender, species) %>%
    count
```

It appears (h/t to Frank) that the count function can take the grouping fields directly:

```
starwars %>% count(gender, species)
```

Comment: @Frank -- a much nicer way. I'll add that.

Answer (score 1):

using data.table,

```
test[, .N, by=.(date, hour)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Base**

```
aggregate(name ~ gender + species, data = starwars, length)
```

If we want to treat NAs as a group:

```
species1 <- factor(starwars$species, exclude = "")
gender1 <- factor(starwars$gender, exclude = "")
aggregate(name ~ gender1 + species1, data = starwars, length)
```